# Getting Error while Updating Docx Js from v5.5.0 to v7.3.0

Tags: javascript, node.js

My app is working fine using docx `v5.5.0` but as soon as I am updating the version to `v7.3.0` I am getting the following error when I try to download the output docx file:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'creator')
    at new Yo (C:\Projects\demo\node_modules\docx\build\index.js:2:291617)
    at DocumentCreator.create (C:\Projects\demo\queries.js:4695:22)
    at C:\Projects\demo\queries.js:4806:33
    at tryCatcher (C:\Projects\demo\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
```

To update the docx.js version I have deleted my `node_modules` folder and then in `package.json` changed the version of docx.js from `5.5.0` to `7.3.0`. And then I ran `npm i` command.

I tried checking for any Github issues related to the same but couldn't find anything.